# Subject filter on reading inbound POP3 connector in Mulesoft

Tags: mule, pop3, connector

We are using POP3 connector as an Inbound to read the email to start the flow.

```
<pop3s:inbound-endpoint  doc:name="Poll emails" host="${email.host}" password="${email.password}" port="${email.port}" responseTimeout="10000" user="${email.user}"/>
```

But this is reading all the emails which are delivered to INBOX, can we restrict the email to be select for read before we read and sent to the flow?

Means, Can we apply any filter on POP3 connector , to send a request to email server to read the mails with Spacific subject.
Mule Runtime is 3.8/Anypoint Studio is 6.1.

Could you please provide your valuable suggestions.

Thank you,
Raj

Answer (score 0):

There a number of ways to filter emails with a specific subject:

**1. Use Email Transport-specific filters**

MuleSoft provides two implementations for inbound-enpoint email transports (POP3, SMTP, IMAP):

- **org.mule.providers.email.filters.AbstractMailFilter:** A base filter implementation that must be extended by any other mail filter.
- **org.mule.providers.email.filters.MailSubjectRegExFilter:** Applies a regular expression to a Mail Message subject.

For example, you can define a `MailSubjectRegExFilter` in the following manner:

```
<flow>
    <pop3s:inbound-endpoint doc:name="Poll emails" host="${email.host}" password="${email.password}" port="${email.port}" responseTimeout="10000" user="${email.user}"/>
    <custom-filter class="org.mule.transport.email.filters.MailSubjectRegExFilter" doc:name="Custom">
        <message-property-filter pattern="subject=mySubject" caseSensitive="true" doc:name="Message Property"/>
    </custom-filter>
    ...
</flow>
```

More information can be found in the following MuleSoft documentation:

- [Email Transport Reference](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/email-transport-reference#filters)
- [Filters Configuration Reference](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/filters-configuration-reference)

**2. Use the Message Filter**

From MuleSoft's blog post [Integration Patterns: Message Filter](http://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/mule-dev/integration-patterns-message-filter/):

> Use a special kind of Message Router, a Message Filter, to eliminate undesired messages from a channel based on a set of criteria.

A sample flow:

```
<flow name="flowWithFilter">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="inQueue"/>
    <message-filter onUnaccepted="DeadLetterQueueFlow" throwOnUnaccepted="false">
        <expression-filter evaluator="xpath" expression="/order/@type = 'book'">
    </message-filter>
    <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="outQueue"/>
</flow>
```

Check the article for more example and configurations.

**3. Build a custom filter**

Crear a Java class that implemnts "Filter" and evaluate if the subject meets your criteria. The examples below have been taken from the article [How to add a custom filter to an email inbound endpoint](https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/ka434000000TPDwAAO/How-to-add-a-custom-filter-to-an-email-inbound-endpoint) and refer to IMAP but it should be similar for POP3.

XML configuration:

```
<flow name="main">
    <imaps:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="imapsConnector" user="someAccount@gmail.com" password="theAccountPassword" host="imap.gmail.com" port="993" doc:name="IMAP">
        <message-filter>
            <custom-filter class="filters.MyCustomEmailFilter" />
        </message-filter>
    </imaps:inbound-endpoint>
    <logger level="INFO" message="Email matched filter, do processing..." doc:name="Logger" />
</flow>
```

Filter class:

```
     public class MyCustomEmailFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(MuleMessage message) {
        MimeMessage emailMessage = (MimeMessage) message.getOriginalPayload();
        try {
            return customEvalLogic(emailMessage);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new MuleRuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private boolean customEvalLogic(MimeMessage emailMessage) throws MessagingException {
        return emailMessage.getSubject().contains("order");     // Please define custom email filter criteria here
    }

}
```